# Access a recurring series to get the details of individual booking

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

Is there any way that I can `Access` a recurring calendar series and get the individual booking details for each day by using `EWS` in Exchange (To get the day, time,location for each)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible with EWS. Below is a C# example.

Here is a list of fields available to you from the [AppointmentSchema Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointmentschema?view=exchange-ews-api)

```
public static Collection<Appointment> FindRecurringCalendarItems(ExchangeService service, 
                                                                    DateTime startSearchDate, 
                                                                    DateTime endSearchDate)
{
    // Instantiate a collection to hold occurrences and exception calendar items.
    Collection<Appointment> foundAppointments = new Collection<Appointment>();
    // Create a calendar view to search the calendar folder and specify the properties to return.
    CalendarView calView = new CalendarView(startSearchDate, endSearchDate);
    calView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, 
                                            AppointmentSchema.Subject, 
                                            AppointmentSchema.IsRecurring, 
                                            AppointmentSchema.AppointmentType
                                            AppointmentSchema.Start,
                                            AppointmentSchema.Location);
    // Retrieve a collection of calendar items.
    FindItemsResults<Appointment> findResults = service.FindAppointments(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, calView);
    // Add all calendar items in your view that are occurrences or exceptions to your collection.
    foreach (Appointment appt in findResults.Items)
    {
        if (appt.AppointmentType == AppointmentType.Occurrence || appt.AppointmentType == AppointmentType.Exception)
        {
            foundAppointments.Add(appt);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Discarding calendar item of type {0}.", appt.AppointmentType);
        }
    }
    return foundAppointments;
}
```

Comment: The individual booking details appearing blank when i tried with this.Please find teh screenshot attached

Comment: Yes, I have used the same code that you have provided

Comment: Actually things are working fine with the code..but the retrieved data is showing exception.You can view the same in the screenshot over there

Comment: Very hard to help you with the information you have given but make sure you have appointments within the time range (`startSearchDate` and `endSearchDate`)

Comment: Is there any possible way that i can get the individual booking details based on the Original Parent Reccurance Meeting ID?